# build.gradle: How to solve "Unable to resolve dependency for" error?

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am getting this gradle error when i build my app:

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0.

here in my app.gradle dependencies code
[here is the image screenshot of the app.gradle file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHg81.png)

> buildgradle  file

[buildgradle file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mGCi.png)

> here are the gradle files codes

Comment: Please take some time to read the help pages, especially the sections named [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) Also please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What's the Error in LogCat after run

Comment: no internet connection.

Comment: checkout what are the things could cause issues for gradle trying to communicate to server. if you're using a proxies disable them then try again. make sure there is no restriction on your internet for google and jcenter servers

Answer (score 0):

you need to add repository `mavenCentral()` into `allprojects`'s `repositories`.

and please, don't post IDE screenshots, because it's painful to work with such input.